# Css Style not working?

Tags: css

It may just be me, but sometimes I think im starting to get the hang of this css stuff' and then it goes back to 'I dont have a clue.'

so, I have a default style

```
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0 none;
  text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

but on a couple of `<a href..>` I need to overwrite the style,
so I have added the following to my css

```
a.myBlue a.myBlue:hover {
  color: #3078ef ;
}
.myBlue a:hover {
     color: #3078ef ;
}
```

(Yes, I've done this twice)

and applied

```
<a href="/Client/Edit/@item.ClientId" class="myBlue"></a>
```

But in Chrome, looking at developer tools its still applying the standard style, it does not even pull "myBlue" down?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It may be a caching issue. Try clearing your cache. Also, unless you put some text in your anchor element, you won't be able to see it.

Comment: `myBlue` is the class of the `a` so just use `.myBlue:hover{...}`

Comment: Missing a comma... a.myBlue , a,myBlue:hover

Comment: `a.myBlue a.myBlue:hover` should be `a.myBlue, a.myBlue:hover`. I've voted to close the question as a *simple typographical error*.

Answer (score 5):

The css selector:

```
a.myBlue a.myBlue:hover
```

Means "Any `a` of class `myBlue` that is being hovered over *and is a child element* of an `a` of class `myBlue`.

If you wish to apply the same style to multiple selectors, you need to separate each selector with a comma:

```
a.myBlue, a.myBlue:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo mistake in your code...Use below code. it works...

```
a.myBlue, a.myBlue:hover {
  color: #3078ef ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is wrong, how you've got it present means it only applies the rule when you hover over an element with the class of `.myBlue` which is the child of another element with the class of `.myBlue`.  So instead your selector needs to be

```
a.myBlue, a.myBlue:hover { /* notice the comma */
  color: #3078ef ;
}
```